# How to send/receive a used phone from USA to Europe, what about duties and tax?

Tags: shipping, imports, postal-system, costs

A friend from the United States wants to give me a used phone, free of charge. The only cost that I should be concerned with are the duties/VAT, I think (Poland).

How should we send/declare the package and its value (it would go through the USPS) to pay the least amount? The phone new was $800 US, now used (and in slightly broken - cracked glass state) it goes for around $400 US.

Should the declared value be that $400? Will the tax be calculated based on the average price of this particular used model or will I have to provide the original invoice and pay a tax based on the $800 value? And also, should this phone be sent in its original box?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it has nothing to do with travel.

Comment: How would mailing a used phone internationally be any different from mailing any used object? Pack it, take it to the post office, fill out the customs form stating contents and value (if really paranoid, fill out the customs form at the post office and take pictures of the form and detailed ones of the object before sealing the package), and pay the postage. Buy insurance if desired. On the receiving end, Polish Customs may or may not open the package, and may or may not charge duty on whatever value they think is warranted.